Syncing Data Transfer Between S3 Buckets Using AWS SDK and Temporal SDK"
able to transfer data from s3 source bucket to s3 destination bucket and its work in sync way like when ever the source get update i should send automatically that date to the destination bucket and if any error happens in the get or in the post it do the process until it finish the task   so I want to complete this without use of any AWS paid service and "temporal sdk" I am using it if there is any other way please help to solve this problem  preferred programming language is nodejs
temporal configuration code with setup explanation or any other technology which can able to solve the problem with nodejs

Sorry, but your requirement is somewhat hard to understand (it's a very long sentence!). Are you saying that when an object is created in Bucket-A, you would like it automatically replicated in Bucket-B? If so, you can configure Bucket-A to automatically replicate objects to Bucket-B. See: Replicating objects - Amazon Simple Storage Service

yes when ever an object created in the bucket A i want that object "automatically" send/transfer to the bucket B

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It appears that your requirement is:

Whenever an object is created in Bucket-A
The object should be automatically copied to Bucket-B

You can do this with Amazon S3 Replication
There are two options available:

Same Region Replication, and
Cross Region Replication

There is no extra charge for using this feature -- you just pay for the normal cost of copying and storing the additional objects.

thanks but i am looking for a method using "Temporal" https://learn.temporal.io/getting_started/typescript/dev_environment/
